# delay foreach until xmlhttprequest finishes the work

Tags: javascript

I tried to find an answer in StackOverflow and even searched elsewhere on the Internet, but I've had no luck. I have been trying for a couple of days now with no success.

I just need to delay my `forEach` until the `XMLHttpRequest` is completed for each file, based on my code below. Thanks in advance..

```
function handleFiles(files,i) {
   files = [...files]
   files.forEach(uploadFile)
}

function uploadFile(file, i) { 
  var Url_imageAdd = "mytargetUrl...."
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var formData = new FormData()
  xhr.open('POST', Url_imageAdd, true)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
  })

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('lConfirm').innerHTML="Files uploaded...."

      urlCount = parseInt($('#urlCount').val())
      $('#urlCount').val(urlCount+filescount)
      var imageSet = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
      alert("Upload Error....")
      window.location.reload();
    }
  })

  formData.append('img_file', file)
  formData.append('title',"mytitle")
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

Comment: So, do you want to wait for all `uploadFile` function executions to complete before moving on?

Comment: I need the next upload to run only after the previous upload is done.

Comment: Check my answer. You can await in a for loop, effectively waiting for each file before moving to the next one.

Comment: I tried that but it is still going not the way i want it, actually I just need it to wait for 2 seconds before starting the next file.... your answer seems good for me, but just if i can make that forEach wait for this couple seconds

Comment: It is easy to add the 2 seconds delay. Just add a `setTimeout` that resolves a promise after to second. It would be: uploadFile -> then setTime (with two seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `uploadFile` function returns a Promise, then you can use `await` or a `.then(...)` callback with `Promise.all`:

```
function uploadFile(file, i) { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var Url_imageAdd = "mytargetUrl...."
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var formData = new FormData()
    xhr.open('POST', Url_imageAdd, true)
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
      updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
    })

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('lConfirm').innerHTML="Files uploaded...."

        urlCount = parseInt($('#urlCount').val())
        $('#urlCount').val(urlCount+filescount)
        var imageSet = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        resolve(imageSet)
      } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
        reject(new Error("Upload Error...."))
      }
    })

    formData.append('img_file', file)
    formData.append('title',"mytitle")
    xhr.send(formData)
  });
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
async function handleFiles(files,i) {
   files = [...files]

   try {
     await Promise.all(files.map(uploadFile));
     // We've finished
   } catch (err) {
     alert('Upload failed!');
     window.location.reload();
   }
}
```

Or if you want to run them in series instead of parallel, with a 2 second delay between:

```
function delay(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
  });
}

async function handleFiles(files,i) {
  files = [...files]

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
        try {
          await delay(2000);
          await uploadFile(files[i], i);
        } catch (err) {
          alert('Upload failed!');
          window.location.reload();
        }
      }

  // We've finished
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I got it, based on your answer I added a function just to delay for 2 seconds and modified your code a bit, and it works like charm. I will edit it your answer and mark it.

Comment: Thanks. Modified it a bit. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your technical constraints.

With the latest technology, try to use await/async call:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Otherwise, improve your solution, hold the result of each XMLHttpRequest and process after all are done.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions for this like for example using `promise` or `callback` But I will share you a solution using `recursion` method:
Edit: Updated to avoid global variable

```
function handleFiles(files, i) {
   files = files;
   count = files.length;
   currentFileIndex = 0;

   uploadFile(files);
}

function uploadFile(files) { 
  const file = files[0]
  .
  .
  .

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('lConfirm').innerHTML="Files uploaded...."

      urlCount = parseInt($('#urlCount').val())
      $('#urlCount').val(urlCount+filescount)
      var imageSet = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)

      // Recursion
      let moreFiles = files.slice(1);
      if (moreFiles.length) {
        uploadFile(moreFiles);
      }

    } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
      alert("Upload Error....")
      window.location.reload();
    }
  })

  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Use of global variable should be avoided. Try passing all files rather than single file and then process first one in the array and call itself with the rest if there were more than one file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two changes:

1. Change the `uploadFile` function to return a promise
2. Use a normal for loop, instead of `forEach` to iterate and await for each file.

Check [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/).